# Action Bar Tab change with tablet orientation

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I have a activity with some fragment inside this activity.

My problem happens when change the orientation the tablet horizontal to vertical.
The action bar tab change, and not stay equals when change the orientation.

When change the orientation the other fragments tabs disappear and i don't know why. I post two images. The first before the change and the second after change.

Here is some of code....

[image]

[image]

```
  @Override
public void onTabSelected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Fragment fragment = tab.getFragment();
    //Fragment fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAB_MAIN);
    if(fragment==null){
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        tab.setFragment(fragment);
        ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tab.getTag());
    }else{
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }       
}

  Inside the manifest....
     <activity android:name="ClientEditActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
              android:screenOrientation="unspecified"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you rotate the screen, Android destroy all Activities and rebuilds they. Maybe you need to check your code to see if some Activity create/destroy the buttons on ActionBar.

Can you put the code that create the ActionBar?